# No rule to make target 'lib/sha256.c' error when compiling kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I am trying to compile kernel module in Fedora 28. My current kernel is `4.17.3-200.fc28.x86_64`. My hello.c is

```
#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h> /* Needed for the macros */
static int __init hello_2_init(void)
{
 printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, world 2\n");
 return 0;
}
static void __exit hello_2_exit(void)
{
 printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, world 2\n");
}
module_init(hello_2_init);
module_exit(hello_2_exit);
```

and my Makefile is

```
obj−m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

I get this error when I am trying to compile. Initially I thought that the error is due to ssl library. So I installed `openssl-devel` for fedora. But I still get the same error.

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.17.3-200.fc28.x86_64/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/4.17.3-200.fc28.x86_64'
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'lib/sha256.c', needed by 'arch/x86/purgatory/sha256.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:263: archprepare] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/4.17.3-200.fc28.x86_64'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: You forget to define `PWD` variable in your Makefile. As you can see, the first line in the build log contains just `M=`.

Comment: I tried adding `PWD := $(shell pwd)` after line no 1 . but still I didn't get .ko file

Comment: Which error did you get with correct `M=` option?

Comment: the patebin link of the error is https://pastebin.com/raw/UBGdNPMv

Comment: You have **non-standard symbol** instead of dash in `obj−m`.

Comment: yeah. Now I get it. Basically I copy pasted the code from a pdf that belong to lkmpg. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
obj-m   := FILENAME.o

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build  <br/>
PWD       := $(shell pwd)

all: 
      default

default:  
      $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules


clean:
      rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions
```

**Try this Makefile or write in Console:**

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` modules obj-m=FILENAME.o
```

**Replace FILENAME with the name of your file!**